# Android Studio - Failed to create keystore

Tags: java, android, linux, android-studio

I'm trying to run my app from inside Android Studio, but every time I try i get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:validateSigningDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: 
com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: 
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create 
keystore.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

Searching for a solution online did not lead me to a suitable one.
Running it with the --debug option gives me this result:

```
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':android:validateSigningDebug'.
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
15:21:41.278 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] 
15:21:41.279 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

The OS I'm using is Archlinux and the permissions for the .android folder are:

```
$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x  4 speedking speedking    4096 15 nov 11.59 .android
```

Can anyone help me please?

Edit:
Building a signed apk does work, just running the app from Android Studio doesn't.

Running it with --stacktrace outputs this:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android:validateSigningDebug'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':android:validateSigningDebug'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedException(UncheckedException.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:141)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:731)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:705)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:267)
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.write(SynchronizedFile.java:232)
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.createIfAbsent(SynchronizedFile.java:328)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ValidateSigningTask.validate(ValidateSigningTask.java:90)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
... 39 more
Caused by: com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile$ActionExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.lambda$createIfAbsent$0(SynchronizedFile.java:336)
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.doActionWithMultiProcessLocking(SynchronizedFile.java:265)
... 43 more
Caused by: com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.createNewStore(KeystoreHelper.java:158)
at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.createDebugStore(KeystoreHelper.java:105)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.ValidateSigningTask.lambda$validate$0(ValidateSigningTask.java:111)
at com.android.builder.utils.SynchronizedFile.lambda$createIfAbsent$0(SynchronizedFile.java:334)
... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.IDEA$Mappings"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.loadAlgorithms(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.setup(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.access$000(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider$1.run(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.generateKeyAndCertificate(KeystoreHelper.java:254)
at com.android.ide.common.signing.KeystoreHelper.createNewStore(KeystoreHelper.java:143)
... 47 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

Comment: Did you try `Run with --stacktrace` to get a more detailed breakdown of what crashed.

Comment: @Dayan I've edited the question including the output of the stacktrace, it doesn't help me much understanding the cause of the problem though

Comment: Did you found a solution, i have the exact same problem?

Comment: Yes, I followed this guide and I managed to get it fixed

https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

Comment: @Nicolò so you didn't have a keystore at all? If that's the case, can you post an answer and accept it so that other people who find this question can learn from it?

Comment: @DenisKniazhev what I did not have was a **debug** keystore, anyway I've posted my answer.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78106583/6401241

Answer (score 8):

It turned out I didn't have a **debug keystore**. A debug keystore is used to sign Android apps during development, to generate it I just typed this command in the terminal:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

as stated in this guide:
https://coderwall.com/p/r09hoq/android-generate-release-debug-keystores

Comment: Same error/issue. And this fix worked. Placing the debug.keystore file in `~/.android` was necessary for me.

Answer (score 1):

I kept getting this error too...to fix it:

1. create a new project using the `Basic Activity` template (but any template probably works)

   - in `Android Studio` > `File` > `New` > `New Project...` > `Basic Activity` > `Next` > re-name if needed > `Finish`
2. after builds, run the app on a device/emulator
3. now, run broken project we are trying to fix, and it should be working (tada!)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running some Gradle stuff, just change from whatever you have there, and choose what to run: Application or whatever you have, but not gradle. [image: run the app, not gradle]

Comment: I have the default "android" configuration that Android Studio puts there