# What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDebug'

Tags: flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

[here is the exception I get when I try to run simple flutter app on my physical device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8sG0.png)

I was working flutter projects on Android studio and run it successfully , but after I update it with flutter and dart , I coudn't even run a simple app .. it requires me a unique application Id

[here is how  my build.gradle file looks like with the to do hint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKOZx.png)

Comment: flutter clean and run the project.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `Failed to create keystore`, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48191724)

Comment: I used to work without adding keystroke before I updated it, is it compulsory to add keystroke just to run app for test?

Comment: Generally, the Keystore is created automatically via android studio once you run the application for the first time (on a machine).
If you've reset your machine then it will be created automatically during the process.
Try creating the keystone manually through the above link and try running the application again.