# Why it shows error "failed to create keystore " in android studio?This is happening when I create a keystore for signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio, android-keystore

Why it showing failed to create keystore?

I tried alot but not working.
I entered all correct information but it working.

Answer (score 12):

This happened to me when I used a comma in my **Organization** name. For example, if you try `Company, Inc` it will fail. I removed the comma and it worked after that fine. I believe this is a bug in the tool and that the comma just needs to be escaped.

Comment: I don't have any commas or dots and still that stupid error, only spaces in organization between words

Comment: what about the other fields? They probably have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you.  A comma was my problem.  Sure should be nice if it gave better feedback.

Comment: For me it was just invalid path in the path field. They should highlight which field is incorrect, it is very unfriendly UI/UX.

Answer (score 2):

idk why but you can
open jdk\bin dir from cmd and type this line :
"keytool -genkey -v -keystore drive:\adress\keyName.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias aliasName"
and then fill all question.
now key generated so use "choose existing key" button and go to your dir and select key. if dont see key there, drag and drop key from dir that key generated to android studio "choose existing key" dialog and then select it.
hope this be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try clicking the folder icon in the "Key store path: " field.
I gotthe error when I manually entered a relative path or simply a file name.
After I clicked the folder icon, and used the dialog, it composed an absolute path and I was able to create the keystore.

Answer (score 1):

For me it failed because I entered a path to existing folder as key store path.

I have long forgotten what is the java keystore, so I created a folder named keystore and specified its path in the dialog field before confirming the dialog. As it turned out the keystore is a file not a folder, so Android Studio could not create a file since there was a folder already. I got "Permission denied" error.

I have added the .jks extension and the keystore file was successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these steps to fix "failed to create keystore"

1. Check `idea.log` in `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\log`
2. Search for this error in logs:

   com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to create keystore.
3. Check error and found this log!

   IllegalArgumentException: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "òôðóðõðùððõóG
4. So i find out it related to date. now i change date region in settings and worked

[image]

5. As it mentions in image you must restart android studio and retry to create key store